# Does $U=U_1(\mathbb{Z}G)$ normalize $G$?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, group-rings

Let $G$ is an arbitrary group and and $U=U_1(\mathbb{Z}G)$ is the set of normalized units of $ZG$ i.e.  $U_1(\mathbb{Z}G)$ here means units of $\mathbb{Z}G$ with augmentation $1$, i.e. set of all elements $u=\sum_{g\in G} a(g)g \in U(\mathbb{Z}G)$ such that $\sum_{g \in G} a(g)=1$.

Now if $U$ contains $G$ and [$U:G$] is finite, then why does it imply that $G$ contains a subgroup $H$ which is normal and of finite index in $U$.

If I take $H=G$, then index point is satisfied **but does $U$ normalize $G$?**
I do not think so, but if it does how to prove it?

Comment: Intersect all the subgroups of $U$ which are conjugate to $G$ to obtain $H$.

Comment: Your second question does not make sense, I think: the subgroup $H$ is constructed from $G$, so you cannot then «take $G=H$».

Comment: ohh ya  it works. Thanks.